# Call javascript function from Capacitor Java

Tags: capacitor

//solution is:

import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {

//in my case I call it the JS function when I press the back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    WebView webView = getBridge().getWebView();

    webView.loadUrl("javascript:pressBack()");

    // in Index.html create tag
    //     <script type="text/javascript">
    //function  pressBack(){
    //    alert('yes!!')
    //} </script>

    return;
}
```

}
// it works fine 100%

Comment: And what is the question?